# Defining a has many through relationship with polymorphism

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm adding a reporting feature to an existing application, the reports are made against one of two models (ideally could also be made against both but let's start small). The reports are configurable and the user should have the ability to "save" a set of filters to a new "Report Type" and setup optional recurring reports with those filters.

The trouble I'm having is how to show only the report types related to each model on their respective dashboards. Each report type will either apply to tests or tickets, but it doesn't have a direct relationship to a ticket or test, just it's class.

[image: Entity relationship diagram, ReportType has many Reports, Report belongs to one report type, reports have many tickets or tests and tickets or tests have many reports]

My initial thought was to use a hasManyThrough relationship but I am unsure how to do that through a polymorphic relationship, and how to query that for purposes of building a menu for the reports that is dynamic.

The end goal is to be able to generate the dropdown menu options and the tab headers in this mockup dynamically, if a model type (Ticket or Test) HAS Report Types then it should appear in the top dropdown menu and when you select it the tabs on the report page should only show the Report Types that have some kind of relationship to that model, so if there is a monthly ticket report then show that tab but don't show monthly test reports for example.

[image]

How do I go about creating the relationship between a ReportType (instance) and the models it could potentially be reporting on (Ticket, Test, etc).